# problem reading panda csv file into python

Tags: pandas, csv

I have a very elementary csv reading program which does not work

`import pandas as pd`

## Reading the tips.csv file

```
 data = pd.read_csv('tips.csv')`
```

The error messages are long and end with tips.csv not found

Comment: most likely your `tips.csv` is not locatad in the same folder as your script, try showing it's location as `data = pd.read_csv(r'C:/test/tips.csv')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your csv file in the same folder?

Comment: I do not have the csv file how do I get it inot my folder

Comment: You need to download the csv file if you haven't already. Then the easiest way is to copy and paste it in the same folder as your script.